# spring batch object creation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am very new to Spring batch.I need to develop a spring batch application which reads 1,00,000 records from csv file. i have developed one spring batch application like below.

```
<job id="hellojob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">       
       <step id="orderprocessor">  
            <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">  
                 <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="500" skip-limit="2">  
                      <skippable-exception-classes>  
                           <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />  
                      </skippable-exception-classes>  
                 </chunk>  
            </tasklet>                 
       </step>  
  </job>
```

Also I am having field set mapper class as

```
public class OrderDataMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Product> {

    @Override
    public Order mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

        Product product = new Product();
        order.setCustId(fieldSet.readString(0));
        order.setOrderNum(fieldSet.readString(1));
        order.setCountry(fieldSet.readString(2));
        return product;

    }

}
```

As per my understanding ,the above field set mapper class is called for every record and each time it creates one new object. So for 1,00,000 records it will create 1,00,000 objects.

I feel these are large number of objects for jvm to handle and are not available for garbage collection as everything runs on single
thread.

Please let me know Is there any way where i can create less number of objects while iterating 1,00,000 records

Comment: The maximum number of objects per chunk is specified in commit-interval; after every chunk commit the 500 created objects are available for garbage collection. I don't understand your statement about GC: garbage collector - as I know - works in a dedicated daemon thread different from application thread

Answer (score 0):

`ItemReader` and `ItemProcessor` handle objects individually. However, `ItemWriter` is handled with fragmentation mode, with the definition of confirmation interval.

Therefore, if the confirmation interval is set to 500, Spring Batch will store the read and / or processed items and execute `ItemWriter` when it reaches the indicated number.

From that moment, the objects will be available to be eliminated by the GC.